# Function calculate the mean

Tags: arrays, function, loops, double, mean

I'm trying to calculate the mean of numbers using a function with an int number of the total double numbers in my array, but i just feel my function is awful, any advice on how i can improve my function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

double meanOfPositive(double *arr, int length);

int main()
{
    int numValue = 6;
    double numbers[] = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6 };
    double mean2;

    mean2 = meanOfPositive(numValue, numbers);

    printf("Mean of all numbers is %.2f", mean2);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

double meanOfPositive(double *arr, int length)
{
    int numValue = 6;
    double tot = 0;
    double mean = 0;
    double numbers[] = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6};

    for (int i = 0; i < numValue; i++)
    {
        tot = tot + numbers[i];
    }
    mean = tot / numValue;
    return mean;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I would do is the following:

```
double mean(double arr[], int len)
{
    double total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        total += arr[i];
    return total / len;
}
```

and then you call it from main like this:

```
double mean2 = mean(numbers, numValue);
```